# Identify Bush in Riga, Latvia

Tags: identification

My toddler somehow managed to chew on few it's leaves and seems to be now suffering with his stomach. Can you please help identify this bush and whether it's leaves are poisonous?

[image]

Comment: I am sorry your son is unwell, I hope he feels better soon.  Are there any other clues you could share with us? Are there any flowers, buds, or fruits on the plant?  Do the leaves have a distinctive smell when you crush them?  It's hard to say, a lot of plants look like that one! Opposing simple elliptic green leaves with serrated edges and pinnate venation, woody shrub with red bark.  The leaves also have that 'ruffly' appearance like spinach or basil, but I don't know how to describe that.

Comment: Thank you @MackM I vaguely remember it has white berries some time during the year. At the moment it has no flowers.

Comment: P.S. It is planted in a park next to the children playground. One would hope no one would plant poisonous plants around baby playgrounds. Probably I am just being paranoid.

Comment: Call emergency medical people right now. We can't diagnose possible poisoning over the internet.

Comment: @Datageek I'm stumped, I was thinking it might be Lonicera ruprechtiana but that has smooth leaf edges.  If you bring a branch to a local greenhouse or the right academic, they might be able to ID it for you.  Please report back if you figure it out!

Comment: Doesn’t look to be any of the very poisonous plants.